# Raising concrete event on abstract class

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following (simplified) setup in my system:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public IReadOnlyList<IEntityEvent> EntityEvents = new();
    
    protected void RaiseEvent(IEntityEvent etEvent)
    {
        EntityEvents.Add(etEvent);
    }
}

public abstract class EntityEvent : IEntityEvent
{
    public Entity RaisingEntity { get; set; }
}
```

An abstract ToggleEntity was made for entities that can be switched on and off by a user to save code re-use.

```
public abstract class ToggleEntity : Entity
{
    public DateTime? DateDeactivated {get; set; }
    
    public virtual void Activate()
    {
        DateDeactivated = null;
    }
    
    public virtual void Deactivate()
    {
        DateDeactivated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public abstract class ActivatedEntityEvent<T> : EntityEvent where T : ToggleEntity
{
}
```

There is a need to capture specific entity events within the system. For example, when a Foo or Bar is activated/deactivated:

```
public class Foo : ToggleEntity
{
}

public class Bar : ToggleEntity
{
}

public class FooActivatedEvent : ActivatedEntityEvent<Foo>
{
}

public class BarActivatedEvent : ActivatedEntityEvent<Bar>
{
}
```

Rather than override the Activated and Deactivated methods on each entity, and raise the specific events, I would like to raise the event within the method on the abstract ToggleEntity class:

```
//within ToggleEntity
public virtual void Activate()
{
    DateDeactivated = null;
    base.RaiseEvent(new EntityActivatedEvent<T>());
}
```

The solution I've come up with so far is something like this:

```
public static class ToggleEventManager
{
    private static Lazy<ActivatedEventCollection> _activatedEventTypes = new Lazy<ActivatedEventCollection>(() => new ActivatedEventCollection());
    private static ActivatedEventCollection ActivatedEventTypes => _activatedEventTypes.Value;

    public static EntityActivatedEvent<T> GetConcreteActivatedEvent<T>() where T : ToggleEntity
    {
        IEnumerable<EntityActivatedEvent<T>> events = ActivatedEventTypes.ConcreteActivatedEventTypes
            .Select(r => Activator.CreateInstance(r) as EntityActivatedEvent<T>);

        return events.FirstOrDefault(f => f.RaisingEntity is T);
    }

    private class ActivatedEventCollection
    {
        internal Type[] ConcreteActivatedEventTypes { get; }

        public ActivatedEventCollection()
        {
            ConcreteActivatedEventTypes = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(p => typeof(EntityActivatedEvent<>).IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsAbstract)
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work however because I don't have T when I try to use the manager to get the concrete event ("The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage"). If I add T to ToggleEntity I get "There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'ToggleEntity'".

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you override a method such as `IEntityEvent CreateEvent()` on each entity?

Comment: Sorry I I'm not understanding right, but would that no be the same as overriding the Activate() method?